# How to interact with multiple console windows?

Tags: node.js

how can interact with multiple console windows, from one node.js script?

so far i have researched a bit, and not have found anything that covers my case.

What i want to accomplish is to have one main console window, which it reads my input,

```
1. action#1
2. action#2

> do 1 // select action
```

and it would redirect its output to another console window named as `Logger` which shows the `stdout` of the action that the user selected, but keeps the main "select action" console window clean.

Comment: The "standard" way to do this is probably to log to a file or to stderr, and have another console window that you open yourself tail that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well i manage to find a way around it, since i wanted to stay with node.js all the way.

**`start.js`**

```
var cp = require("child_process");
cp.exec('start "Logger" cmd /K node logger.js',[],{});
cp.exec("start cmd /K node startAdminInterface.js",[],{});
setTimeout(function(){process.exit(0);},2000);
```

**`logger.js`**

```
var net = require('net');
net.createServer(function (socket) {
  socket.on('data',function(d){
    console.log(": "+d.toString("utf8"));
  });
  socket.on('error',function(err){
    console.log("- An error occured : "+err.message);
  });
}).listen(9999);
```

**`startAdminInterface.js`**

```
var net = require("net");
var logger = net.connect(9999);
var readline = require('readline'),
    rl = readline.createInterface(process.stdin,process.stdout);
rl.setPrompt('> ');
rl.prompt();
rl.on('line', function(line) {
  logger.write(line);
  rl.prompt();
}).on('close', function() {
  process.exit(0);
});
```

bottom, line its a workaround not exactly what i was after, put i saw potential, on `logger.js` it could listen from multiple sources, which is an enormous plus in the application that i'm building.